# SQL Server changes the value in the float column when converting to varchar

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqldatatypes

I have a column in my table that is of `float` type. The table was automatically generated when I imported the spreadsheet (Excel) data to my database. Thus there is a column I wish to change from `float` to `varchar`, but when I try to do this, I get an error:

> 'tblInvoices' table
>   Unable to create index 'IX_tblInvoices'.
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.tblInvoices' and the index name 'IX_tblInvoices'.
>   The duplicate key value is (1.00001e+006). The statement has been terminated.

It is a unique column, and set that way (not set as the primary key for reasons). I have already run queries to search for and delete duplicate fields but there are none. The query I ran as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
       Invoice,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY Invoice)
   FROM
       dbo.tblInvoices
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```

So the value within the `Invoice` column is 1000010 and when I run the following query a single row is found.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TradeReceivables_APR_IFRS9].[dbo].[tblInvoices] 
WHERE Invoice = 1.00001e+006
```

Note that I have searched for the value in the error, 1.00001e+006, and not 1000010.

So my question is why does the DBMS do this? Why does it change the value like that? When I remove the column, it does it with another column and so on and so on (about 40 000 rows in total). How can I change the column from `float` to `varchar` without changing the data and getting errors?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the field is an integer so you can Cast it to `BIGINT` before cast to `VARCHAR`

```
Declare @Invoice as float = 1.00001e+006
print cast(@Invoice as varchar) -->> Result : 1.00001e+006
print cast(cast(@Invoice as bigint) as varchar) -->> Result : 1000010
```

Comment: I found that out right after I posted this. But thanks for answering. Accepted as the answer!